# How to access route parameters outside the view

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a very simple Angular app for showing information about football tournaments. For each tournament in the database I want to show a view of either the matches or the statistics, so I'm implementing this simple URL scheme:

- `foo/matches`: matches of tournament Foo,
- `foo/stats`: statistics for tournament Foo.

The `index.html` file is structured like this:

```
<nav ng-controller="NavController">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#/{{ t }}/matches"> Matches </a> 
    <li> <a href="#/{{ t }}/status">  Stats </a>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div ng-view></div>
```

and the routes are configured like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:t/matches', {templateUrl: 'partials/matches.html', controller: 'MatchesController'})
    .when('/:t/stats',   {templateUrl: 'partials/stats.html',   controller: 'StatsController'  })
}]);
```

My problem are those `{{ t }}` links in the HTML. I want the links to change the view to the stats or the match list for the current tournament. But since the links are outside the view, so they don't have access to the route parameters (I tried injecting `$routeParams` and all I get is an empty object).

In summary, I haven't been able to create links for changing the view outside of it. The nav bar doesn't know what is the current tournament.

How can I (and what is the best way to) access the current state of the view (in this case, the current tournament) outside of it?

Comment: How do you set the value of `t`. Please show that code.

Comment: `$scope.t = something` in NavController. The "something" is what I want to learn about. Hard-coding a value works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After [reading a bit about scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) I learned how they nest. I solved my problem simply by wrapping both the view and the navigation bar with a new controller:

```
<div ng-controller="NavController">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#/{{ t }}/matches"> Matches </a> 
      <li> <a href="#/{{ t }}/status">  Stats </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

The view will inherit NavController's scope prototypically. I initialized an object in the outer scope, and assigned the desired value to one of its properties in the inner controllers:

```
 app.controller('NavController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.currentTournament = {};
 });

 app.controller('MatchesController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
     // ...
     $scope.currentTournament.id = $routeParams.t;
 });

 app.controller('StatsController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
     // ...
     $scope.currentTournament.id = $routeParams.t;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), you could use the $stateParams service to access state and state variables from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about ui-router. I'll definitely take a look at it when I develop a larger application. For what I'm doing know it'll be overkill to add a dependency just to handle a small use case.